# ASP.NET page automatically opens with defined route instead of Home/Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I defined route mapping to open pages with respect to defined route value in Controller.

When I run `index.cshtml` under Home Folder, it pages open with `https://localhost:44333/Home/Index` with no result but I already defined route in Index function of Controller. When I changed url to `https://localhost:44333/MainPage`, it pages open with `https://localhost:44333/MainPage`.

How can I open page with this url `https://localhost:44333/MainPage` or "`https://localhost:44333/`" automatically when I run the app.

Here is my `Index` function of `HomeController` which is defined below.

```
[RequireHttps]
[Route("")]
[Route("MainPage")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Attribute = "header-transparent";
   return View();
}
```

Here is my RouteConfig.cs file which is shown below.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```

Here is my admin part

```
[Route("panel")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var allCategories = db.Category.ToList();
            return View(allCategories);
        }

        [Route("panel/login")]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

How can do the same process when I run app as `/Admin/Index` and show the url as `panel/login`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a different URL for your route, use `RoutePrefix`.

Here is an example if you want to open `panel/login` instead of `/admin/index`:

```
[RoutePrefix("panel")]
public class AdminController : Controller
```

And for ActionResult:

```
[Route("Login")]
public ActionResult Index()
```